# проверка последовательности чисел на простое число со счетчиком

Tags: python

Хочу написать функцию по проверке последовательности чисел на простоту, вот мой код,что я делаю нет так, поправьте пожалуйста.

```
def isPrime():
  sequence = int(input('Введите количество чисел в последовательности:'))
  count = 0
  for number in range(sequence // 2 + 1):
    if sequence % number == 0:
      return False
  return True
  count += 1
  print(count)
```

Comment: Да много что не так. Проще заново написать, чем исправлять. Сначала продумайте алгоритм, а потом переводите его в код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно или в функцию еще один цикл добавить, или же саму функцию зациклить. Вот наиболее приближенный пример к вашему коду:

```
def is_prime(x):
    """Функция проверки числа на простое"""
    if x < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, (x // 2) + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


sequence = int(input('Введите количество чисел в последовательности:'))
count = 0
for number in range(sequence):
    if is_prime(number):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @SaraK Пожалуйста :)

Comment: @SaraK и не забудьте принять ответ, если он помог

Comment: Проверять достаточно до корня из числа, т.е. где-то `int(x**0.5)+1`, это сильно сокращает перебор для больших чисел.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, вы правы. Как то не учел этот момент, спасибо

Comment: @CameL Просто всякие простые числа тут миллион раз уже обсуждались по всякому, я уже просто помню это )

Answer (score 1):

`range` по умолчанию начинается с 0 -> [документация](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp), а значения 0 и 1 для проверки некорректны.

Необходимо отдельно от `isPrime` получить последовательность, а потом в цикле подать её. Чтобы отделить ввод данных от их обработки.

Получать последовательность можно за один `input`, а потом разбить её с помощью `split`, приведение к числу `int("10")`

```
def isPrime(number):
    rangeSize = number // 2 + 1

    for checkingNumber in range(2, rangeSize):
        if number % checkingNumber == 0:
            return False
    return True
    
arr = [3, 5, 7, 20, 14, 17]
count = 0

for item in arr:
    if isPrime(item):
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!